# Binance open API Google Shets JavaScript Websocket ban

Tags: javascript, websocket, binance

I have JavaScript to communicate with the Binance API - it only downloads two data - I can't finish it because I get the message: {"code": - 1003, "msg": "Way too much request weight used; IP banned until 1663675430913. Please use the websocket for live updates to avoid bans. "} Please help me how to create a Websocket at the beginning of the script.

```
function response() {
var depthSocketBuffer;
//fetch(url) Metoda 
var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=XLMUSDT";
//getContentText() formula
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);

//JSON.parse() formula 

//highestBid
var json1 = response
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var bidPrice = data.ticker.bidPrice;
Logger.log(bidPrice)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").setValue(bidPrice);

//lowestAsk
var json2 = response
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var askPrice = data.ticker.askPrice;
Logger.log(lowestAsk)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").setValue(askPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received happens because IP Limits weren't respected on REST API, you can consult the conditions on the [API Documentation (LIMITS section)](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#limits).

As for the websocket, there's actually a Node.js API connector available for public use (with the websocket integrated).
The repository is at https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-node, where you can find the *README.md* file that details its usage.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try to sort it out.